# update wpf datagrid cell from other thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading

I'm trying to implement a simple spreadsheet using WPF datagrid.
When users input a formula in a cell, engine calculates the formula and update the cell with the calculated value. But most of calculations i handle take long time, so i want to calculate those in other threads.

I tried to implement this using CellEditEnding event like below. (the ItemsSource of dataGrid1 is bound to the DataTable dtab.)

```
private void dataGrid1_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e) {
    Action calc = () => {
        int r = dataGrid1.Items.IndexOf(e.Row.Item);
        int c = dataGrid1.Columns.IndexOf(e.Column);
        dtab.Rows[r].SetField(c, "X"); // a calculated value
    };            
    Action update = () => {
        if (dataGrid1.Dispatcher.CheckAccess()) calc();
        else dataGrid1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(calc);
    };

    //update(); // run from the same ui thread
    Task.Factory.StartNew(update); // run from a different thread
}
```

When it update the cell value from the same UI thread, cell is updated with value "X", but from the different thread, it is not. How can i update the cell with value "X" from a different thread?

EDIT: My code does not throw any InvalidOperationException bcz i used the Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(). My problem seems that the user input value (formula) overwrites the calculated value which i want to display.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update the GUI from another thread. Fortunately .Net provides a mechanism to handle this:

```
uiControl.**Dispatcher**.Invoke(delegate)
```

For example

```
dataGrid1.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MyUpdateFunction(dataGrid1, data))
```

Edit: Sorry the original code was for Windows.Forms

Comment: i know about the Dispatcher.Invoke(). You can see my code. I already use it and my code does not throw any InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Sorry I missed that.

The issue might be with the anonymous function closure (i.e.: wrong values are stored).

Did you try setting a breakpoint at the end of Calc routine (where it updates the cell value)?

Comment: One more thing, you might try moving the calculation of r and c outside.

Answer (score 1):

Using dispatcher is not a good idea. It can render your UI non responsive if not coded properly. If you plan to use datagrid in multithreaded setup then you should use events to reflect the updates. I would recommend a combination of ObservableCollection with INotifyPropertyChanged as better alternative. I have published a template here :

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1086714/A-Template-For-Using-Datagrid-in-Monitoring-UI

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [WPF Dispatcher Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx). You have quite a few options to perform threaded tasks from the Dispatcher. Review the BeginInvoke and Invoke methods.